# Hex Dump EXE File

Tags: c#, arrays, hexdump

How do I properly display the contents of an EXE file **"C:/Path/To/File.exe"** in hexadecimal form? So far, I have:

```
byte[] BytArr = File.ReadAllBytes("C:/Path/To/File.exe")
```

I tried using a **switch** statement (not shown here) that reads every few bytes and should output the appropriate hexadecimal code, but it failed. What should I do? I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me.

---

Beware that the answer code isn't well formatted and is rather inefficient (source: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/36747/quick-and-dirty-hexdump-of-a-byte-array), but I did make an effort to format it properly.
**Answer Code:**

```
    using System.Text;

    namespace HexDump  
    {
        class Utils
        {
            public static string HexDump(byte[] bytes, int bytesPerLine = 16)
            {
                if (bytes == null) return "<null>";
                int bytesLength = bytes.Length;

                char[] HexChars = "0123456789ABCDEF".ToCharArray();

                int firstHexColumn =
              8                   // 8 characters for the address
            + 3;                  // 3 spaces

                int firstCharColumn = firstHexColumn
            + bytesPerLine * 3       // - 2 digit for the hexadecimal value and 1 space
            + (bytesPerLine - 1) / 8 // - 1 extra space every 8 characters from the 9th
            + 2;                  // 2 spaces 

                int lineLength = firstCharColumn
            + bytesPerLine           // - characters to show the ascii value
            + Environment.NewLine.Length; // Carriage return and line feed (should normally be 2)

                char[] line = (new String(' ', lineLength - Environment.NewLine.Length) + Environment.NewLine).ToCharArray();
                int expectedLines = (bytesLength + bytesPerLine - 1) / bytesPerLine;
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(expectedLines * lineLength);

                for (int i = 0; i < bytesLength; i += bytesPerLine)
                {
                    line[0] = HexChars[(i >> 28) & 0xF];
                    line[1] = HexChars[(i >> 24) & 0xF];
                    line[2] = HexChars[(i >> 20) & 0xF];
                    line[3] = HexChars[(i >> 16) & 0xF];
                    line[4] = HexChars[(i >> 12) & 0xF];
                    line[5] = HexChars[(i >> 8) & 0xF];
                    line[6] = HexChars[(i >> 4) & 0xF];
                    line[7] = HexChars[(i >> 0) & 0xF];

                    int hexColumn = firstHexColumn;
                    int charColumn = firstCharColumn;

                    for (int j = 0; j < bytesPerLine; j++)
                    {
                        if (j > 0 && (j & 7) == 0) hexColumn++;
                        if (i + j >= bytesLength)
                        {
                            line[hexColumn] = ' ';
                            line[hexColumn + 1] = ' ';
                            line[charColumn] = ' ';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            byte b = bytes[i + j];
                            line[hexColumn] = HexChars[(b >> 4) & 0xF];
                            line[hexColumn + 1] = HexChars[b & 0xF];
                            line[charColumn] = (b < 32 ? '·' : (char)b);
                        }
                        hexColumn += 3;
                        charColumn++;
                    }
                    result.Append(line);
                }
                return result.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to dump file in a specific format?

Comment: Preferably a string, but it doesn't really matter for me. Thanks.

Comment: Does example help?

Comment: An example would help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some simple code that will lump the bytes 4 at a time(step) with a space delimiter(delimiter):

```
int step = 4;
string delimiter = " ";
for(int i = 0; i < BytArr.Length;i += step)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < step; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(BytArr[i + j].ToString("X2"));
    }
    Console.Write(delimiter);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is very useful (answers can be useful in different ways), so I up-voted it. To help prevent confusion among everyone, I decided not to move the "accepted" status to your answer (it was still very helpful), although your code's density and quality is high.

Comment: It should be this one as the other one isn't considered good by Stackoverflow standards as it's content is purely links elsewhere

Comment: In that case, I moved the "accepted" status. We should still give credit to Tectrendz for the effort.

Answer (score -1):

[URL](http://wiki.c2.com/?HexDumpInManyProgrammingLanguages) shows how to dump in C. Search for C sample which is given towards the end of the page.
This [URL](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/36747/quick-and-dirty-hexdump-of-a-byte-array) shows example in C#

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I meant C#, not C (I couldn't find C# in there).

Comment: Added C# example.

Comment: Your answer was really helpful. Thanks (Up- voted and accepted)! I will post the code in my question for people to see.